# Is this correct - period of the order of several thousands of days?

Tags: prepositions

Is this correct, please?

> an orbital period of the order of several thousands of days

Sentence

> This is a binary star system with an orbital period **of the order of several thousands of days**.

I'm interested in knowing if the prepositions are appropriate.

Comment: Please give a full sentence and state what your particular query is. Proofreading is not a service offered by this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a scientist, I would express an uncertain number within a ten-fold range, as *either* “several” *or* “the order of”, but **never both**.  As they express the same idea (differing only in the greater precision of “order of”) if both were used one would always be superfluous. So it’s:

> “…a period of several thousand days”

or

> “…a period *of* the order of a thousand days” ([British English](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/of-the-order-of))

> “…a period *on* the order of a thousand days” ([American English](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/on-the-order-of))

The latter pair would, I think, sound unnatural outside a technical context.

Comment: A more general usage is _on the order of `X`_. It refers to orders of magnitude, i.e, x, 10x, 100x, .... To say something is _on the order of `X`_ means it's more than 1/10 X and less than 10X, in whatever dimension you're measuring. If you're not measuring, then it's metaphorical and not exact.

Comment: @JohnLawler — I know. Isn’t that what I said, or at least implied by “ten-fold range”?

Comment: @David No, not exactly. It's ***on** the order of*, not ***of** the order of*. Only one _of_.

Comment: @JohnLawler — I didn't know that, but you are the mathematician, I believe. I'll check for myself tomorrow and correct.

Comment: No, I am actually the grammarian. I have a degree in math, but that just lets me speak the language.

Comment: @JohnLawler — Please forgive my incorrect order. However in this case it appears to be usage as well as grammar. Collins Dictionary has my "of" as British usage and your "on" as American usage. So I hope we have both learned something.